# JPA, EJB with error HHH000262: Table not found: employee

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, ejb

I have a simple maven project with jpa and ejb, it run on server glassfish 4.1

My persistence.xml file is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="EmployeeService" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.bkstorm.jpa.model.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456a@" />
            
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My entity file Employee.java:

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "sal")
    private int salary;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee id: " + getId() + " name: " + getName() + " salary: " + getSalary();
    }
}
```

I have a ejb session bean:
EmployeeService.java

```html
public interface EmployeeService {

    public Employee createEmployee(String name, int salary);

    public Collection<Employee> findAllEmployees();
}
```

and EmployeeServiceBean.java that implements EmployeeService

```html
@Stateless
public class EmployeeServiceBean implements EmployeeService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EmployeeService")
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Employee createEmployee(String name, int salary) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setName(name);
        emp.setSalary(salary);
        em.persist(emp);
        return emp;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Employee> findAllEmployees() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e");
        return (Collection<Employee>) query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bkstorm.jpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>autoIdGeneration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>autoIdGeneration</name>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For connection pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my error's log:

```html
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Info:   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
 name: EmployeeService
 ...]
Info:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.0.Final}
Info:   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Info:   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Info:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
Info:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Info:   HHH000229: Running schema validator
Info:   HHH000262: Table not found: employee
Info:   HHH000262: Table not found: employee
Severe:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
Severe:   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: EmployeeService] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:753)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [employee]
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:67)
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:484)
 at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
 ... 25 more
Severe:   Exception while preparing the app
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: EmployeeService] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:753)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [employee]
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:67)
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:484)
 at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
 ... 25 more
```

I don't know where the error come form. Any ideas, thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**
Changing "validate" to "update" didn't solve my problem.
The employee table exists in my database.
When I run glassfish server, it show log:

```html
Info:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
Info:   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Info:   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Info:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Info:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Info:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Info:   HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Info:   HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Info:   HHH000396: Updating schema
Info:   HHH000262: Table not found: employee
Info:   HHH000262: Table not found: employee
Info:   HHH000262: Table not found: employee
ERROR:   HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table employee (emp_id integer not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), sal integer, primary key (emp_id)) ENGINE=InnoDB
ERROR:   Syntax error: Encountered "auto_increment" at line 2, column 33.
Info:   HHH000232: Schema update complete
Warning:   The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Warning:   The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Info:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [3700]
Info:   Portable JNDI names for EJB EmployeeServiceBean: [java:global/autoIdGeneration/EmployeeServiceBean!com.bkstorm.jpa.stateless.EmployeeService, java:global/autoIdGeneration/EmployeeServiceBean]
Info:   Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB EmployeeServiceBean: [com.bkstorm.jpa.stateless.EmployeeService#com.bkstorm.jpa.stateless.EmployeeService, com.bkstorm.jpa.stateless.EmployeeService]
Info:   WELD-000900: 2.2.2 (Final)
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Error in linking security policy for autoIdGeneration -- Inconsistent Module State
 at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.SecurityUtil.linkPolicyFile(SecurityUtil.java:336)
 at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.SecurityDeployer.linkPolicies(SecurityDeployer.java:318)
 at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.SecurityDeployer.access$100(SecurityDeployer.java:87)
 at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.SecurityDeployer$AppDeployEventListener.event(SecurityDeployer.java:145)
 at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
 at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
 at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /autoIdGeneration
Severe:   The web application [unknown] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.codegen.impl.CurrentClassLoader$1] (value [org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.codegen.impl.CurrentClassLoader$1@1b057c21]) and a value of type [org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader] (value [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : Error in linking security policy for autoIdGeneration -- Inconsistent Module State
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 14ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Info:   visiting unvisited references
......................
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
 name: EmployeeService
 ...]
Info:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
Info:   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Info:   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Info:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Info:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Info:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Info:   HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Info:   HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Info:   HHH000396: Updating schema
Info:   HHH000262: Table not found: employee
Info:   HHH000262: Table not found: employee
Info:   HHH000262: Table not found: employee
ERROR:   HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table employee (emp_id integer not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), sal integer, primary key (emp_id)) ENGINE=InnoDB
ERROR:   Syntax error: Encountered "auto_increment" at line 2, column 33.
Info:   HHH000232: Schema update complete
Info:   Portable JNDI names for EJB EmployeeServiceBean: [java:global/autoIdGeneration/EmployeeServiceBean!com.bkstorm.jpa.stateless.EmployeeService, java:global/autoIdGeneration/EmployeeServiceBean]
Info:   Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB EmployeeServiceBean: [com.bkstorm.jpa.stateless.EmployeeService#com.bkstorm.jpa.stateless.EmployeeService, com.bkstorm.jpa.stateless.EmployeeService]
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context '/autoIdGeneration'
Info:   Loading application [autoIdGeneration] at [/autoIdGeneration]
Info:   autoIdGeneration was successfully deployed in 7,047 milliseconds.
```

Then, I executes EmployeeServiceBean.fillAllEmployees, an error occurs.
I have no idea what's going on!

Comment: Do you actually have created an `employee` table in your DB? Because if you get an exception and logs telling you "table not found", that is the first you should check...

Comment: the employee table exists in my database.

Answer (score 7):

Change hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto value from 'validate' to 'update' and hibernate creates the table for you.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

Comment: I changed "validate" to "update", but another error appear.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me :

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks suspicious to have both properties defined:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

and

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
```

Both properties are used to tell the JPA provider what to do with the schema. 
The latter exists as of JPA 2.1 and is now the preferred, portable way, so I would suggest to remove the hibernate specific property.